# OpenVPN client assumes server's WiFi IP address on the network

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I will try to explain my setup as brief as possible.
Basically I have a desktop computer connect to a Raspberry Pi via an ethernet cable. The RPi is the OpenVPN Server.

So:

**The Raspberry Pi** is connected to:

- WiFi network and the internet (192.168.1.43 255.255.255.0 | Gateway:
  192.168.1.254)
- Ethernet cable directly to the Windows desktop (10.8.1.1 255.255.255.0)
- OpenVPN server running on 10.8.0.1

**Windows desktop** is connected to:

- WiFi network and the internet (192.168.1.63 255.255.255.0 | Gateway:
  192.168.1.254)
- Ethernet cable directly to Raspberry Pi (10.8.1.2 255.255.255.0)

Everything is working fine. I can access the internet, my desktop and all as a VPN client.

**The problem:**
When connected with another device to the VPN server and given the IP address 10.8.0.2 (for instance), if I ping the Windows PC (10.8.1.2) the IP shown as the ping source is actually the Raspberry Pi's Wi-Fi network card's IP (192.168.1.43) instead of the Ethernet card's IP or the OpenVPN client's IP.

Is there anything I can do so when the VPN client pings/access the Windows PC, it uses its own real IP? (in this case 10.8.0.2)?

This is the route table on the Raspberry Pi:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

I've installed OpenVPN using this script: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/
In the setup process when it asked me my internal IPv4, I typed in the Ethernet's IP 10.8.1.1. I don't know if this makes any difference.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The script you used set up `SNAT` rules. Although it’s not entirely clear how things ended up the way they are. Best to start over from the beginning, this time setting it up manually. It’s not that complicated.

Comment: @DanielB, thank you. I will install it manually from scratch and report back.